# Checking errors if there is any

Tags: python

For ex: i have a class:

```
class foo:
    ipAdress = ipAdress
    value1 = value1
```

I just want to check if the parameters are available in the class `foo`.

I did this :

```
if hasattr(foo,'ipAdress') == False:
        raise AttributeError ('ipAdress has to be specified...')

if hasattr(foo, 'value1') == False:
         raise ValueError ('value1 has to be specified...')
```

my question: Is there any other way to detect this parameter from the class? I don't want to use True or False to specify the attributes.

Any help is appreciated .

many thanks

Comment: How can either of these be missing if they are class attributes?

Comment: Tests like that would normally be written as `if not hasattr(foo,'ipAdress'):`.  Explicit comparisons to `True` or `False` are almost never what you actually want.

Comment: @Sam, what is the purpose or goal you want to achieve? As DeepSpace mentioned, they will be present since they are class variables.

Comment: that's awesome jason, could have never thought that. been still new to this python.

Comment: Well if you have class attributes defined like this they are alway present unless you actively delete them. Is it possible you confused class and instance attributes (usually defined via `self`)?

Comment: @lmiguelvargast and Deepspace , ofcourse they cannot be neglected, jason provided the solution, that was all i meant.I just didn't want to write True or false while writing the program, if not did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want real data validation (ie check that the variables you pass to your class instance comply with certain rules), you should have a look at Pydantic:

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io

Example for your ip address:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv6Address
from pydantic import BaseModel

class myModel(BaseModel):
    ipaddress: IPv4Address
    value1: int
```

You can then create an instance of myModel with your actual arguments.
This will validate your arguments.
You can then pass that instance to your foo class instance.

Comment: I love Python puns... pydantic... :D

Comment: To add something to the discussion, although not necessarily helpful here: The typing module `import typing` adds similar features, where you can assign a typeHINT to an object. This is not enforced, but rather helpful during development.

Comment: @Dustin pydantic also heavily reliés on typing module...but knows more stuff ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vars()` which will return a dictionary of the class attributes, for example like this:

```
class foo:
    
    def attr_valid(self, attr_name):
         return attr_name in vars(self).keys()

f = foo()
```

if i now check for ipAddress, it will return False

```
f.attr_valid("ipAddress")
# Out[34]: False
```

now i set the class variable "ipAddress" and then it will return True

```
f.ipAddress = "123"
f.attr_valid("ipAddress")
#Out[35]: True
```

if you want a function instead of a method you can use it like this:

```
def attr_valid(class_object, attr_name):
    return attr_name in vars(class_object).keys()

f = foo()
attr_valid(f, "ipAddress")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have this

```
class foo:
        ipAddress = ""
        value1 = ""
```

You can setup a check like this..

```
bar = foo()
bar.ipAddress = "127.0.0.1"

if bar.ipAddress == "" or bar.value1 == "":
    raise AttributeError
```

Not the cleanest way, but if you want something without an init, it works.

Comment: The poster did not ask how to check whether the attributes are populated, he wanted to know if they exist (e.g. he used `hasattr()` which tells us if an attribute exists in an object, not if that attribute is populated)

Comment: Ah well, that could be just a misunderstanding of what an attribute is. Most inexperienced people would probably be more interested in knowing if it is populated, vs if it exists.